# Reading Windows Registry with Java 11

Tags: java, module, registry

I am converting an application from Java 8 to Java 11, which means that I have to deal with the modularized JRE. The routine to read a Windows registry key is failing with an InaccessableObjectException; the message is
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private long java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences.openKey(byte[],int,int) accessible: module java.prefs does not "opens java.util.prefs" to module myModule.
The module-info.java file contains the statement "requires java.prefs;".
In the method below, the line "openKey.setAccessible(true);" is throwing the exception. Is there a different statement I should add to the module-info.java file?

```
    public static String getRegistryValue(String key, String name, Logger log) 
{
    String vals = null;
    //Retrieve a reference to the root of the system preferences tree
    final Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
    final Class <?> clz = systemRoot.getClass();

    try {
        Class <?>[] params1 = {byte[].class, int.class, int.class};
        final Method openKey = clz.getDeclaredMethod(
                "openKey", params1);
        openKey.setAccessible(true);

        Class <?>[] params2 = {int.class};
        final Method closeKey = clz.getDeclaredMethod(
                "closeKey", params2);
        closeKey.setAccessible(true);

        final Method winRegQueryValue = clz.getDeclaredMethod(
                                            "WindowsRegQueryValueEx", 
                                            int.class,
                                            byte[].class); 
        winRegQueryValue.setAccessible(true);

        int hKey = (Integer) openKey.invoke(systemRoot, 
                                            toByteEncodedString(key), 
                                            KEY_READ, 
                                            KEY_READ);
        byte[] valb = (byte[]) winRegQueryValue.invoke(systemRoot, hKey,
                  toByteEncodedString(name));
        vals = (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
        closeKey.invoke(Preferences.systemRoot(), hKey);              
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "getRegistryValue failed for " +
                key + "\\" + name);
        JFrame frame =  new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Event viewer cannot be opened.",
                "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return vals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your application with VM option

```
--add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=<your-module-name>
```

where *your-module-name* is the name of your module that requires reflective access to *java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences*.

> Reflectively Accessing Internal APIs With --add-opens
>
> The java option --add-opens $module/$package=$reflectingmodule can be
>   used to open $package of $module for deep reflection to
>   $reflectingmodule. Code in $reflectingmodule can hence reflectively
>   access all types and members in $package but other modules can not.

from https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-hack-java-module-system/